# PHP : Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display my database results in a table but now i am getting this message. `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`

This is my code:

```
$artistsql = "SELECT artist.artistName as 'artist.artistName', 
           artist.artistID as 'artist.artistID',
           publisher.pubName as 'publisher.pubName', 
           cd.CDTitle as 'cd.CDTitle',
           cd.CDID as 'cd.CDID'
    FROM tiptop_cd as cd
    INNER JOIN tiptop_artistcd as artistcd ON(artistcd.CDID = cd.CDID)
    INNER JOIN tiptop_artist as artist ON(artist.artistID = artistcd.artistID)
    INNER JOIN tiptop_publisher as publisher ON(publisher.pubID = cd.pubID)
    WHERE cd.CDTitle = :title";

$stmt = $db->prepare($artistsql);
$stmt->bindParam(":title", $_GET['title']);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$details = $results[0];

$artistsql1 = "SELECT cd.CDTitle as 'cd.CDTitle'
    FROM tiptop_artistcd as artistcd
    INNER JOIN tiptop_cd as cd ON(cd.CDID = artistcd.CDID AND cd.CDID != :cd_id)
    WHERE artistcd.artistID = :artist_id";

$stmt = $db->prepare($artistsql1);
$stmt->bindParam(":artist_id", $details['artist.artistID']);
$stmt->bindParam(":cd_id", $details['cd.CDID']);
$stmt->execute();

echo "<table>".
     "<tr>".
     "<th>Artist Name</th>".
     "<th>Publisher</th>".
     "<th>Other Album</th>".
     "</tr>".

     "<tr>".
     "<td>".$details['artist.artistName']."</td>".
     "<td>".$details['publisher.pubName']."</td>".
     "<td>".$details['cd.CDTitle']."</td>".
     "</tr>";

while ($album = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr style=\"cursor: pointer;\">";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $album['cd.CDTitle'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table";
```

The error is showing at the `$details = $results[0];`. Can I know a way to fix this problem. Because of this i cant display my database results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns associative array. You have to use `$result['artist.artistName']`. Otherwise use `->fetch()` and leave `$results[0]` untouched.

Comment: do you have your database connection correctly set up and called $db

Comment: OR change FETCH_ASSOC to PDO::FETCH_NUM

Comment: anonymous did you get the solution?

Comment: @gavgrif yes i have it

Comment: @Mihai i tried its the same